# Unable to see database table in real device without connecting to xcode

Tags: database, sqlite, react-native

I have inserted data to database in sqlite.I need to see the data in the device without using xcode or android studio.How to see it?

Have added a databasename.db file to the project.How to see the new value inserted to the database.

Comment: You can use the sqlite tool to view data.

Comment: could you tell me?i have a db file which was created locally.It has no change affected if any value inserted to the database.How to see that new data?

Comment: Did you insert the data using the sqlite tool?

Comment: the database was created using sqlite db browser and the  data was inserted programmatically

Comment: Will my data be the same if I close the program and reopen the file? Did the data you attempted to insert complete successfully?

Comment: i can see the inserted data from xcode. But i want to see the data outside xcode or android studio.